# is it possible to introduce fractional delay in waveform in GNURadio?

Tags: gnuradio

I know this is a strange question as its hard to do in digital domain. I know it is a straight forward task if the signal is defined within N number of samples where I can go to Fourier transform multiplied by complex sinusoidal with inverse period of that fractional delay and then come back to time domain through IFFT. Is it possible to do in GNURadio ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, using a filter delay

Comment: Very good overview on fractional delays: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/482137

Comment: i remember that.  it was in the IEEE Signal Processing magazine.  the second author Vesa Valimaki is an AES acquaintance of mine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right reference.